# How do i keep a contract's value changed by another one constant?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, truffle-contract, pending-transactions

There are 3 contracts; `A`, `B`, and `C`. `C` has a state variable with a default value. `A` changes that state variable to `Yerevan`. After that, `B` sees that variable. Evaluating by `A` is successful but `B` sees the default value again. It appears that `B` cannot call a updated smart contract. How can i change a state variable by an other smart contract permanently? is there any related work? please guide a beginner man. Thank you.

C:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

contract C{
   bytes public name;
   function rep(bytes memory pseudonym)  public returns(string memory){
       name=pseudonym;
       return string(name);
   }
   }
```

A:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
import "./C.sol";
contract A{
   bytes public fname="Yerevan";
   function naming() public returns(string memory){
      return C(0x8fcECc5B8d42EcF099E1cF032B1F505fbDA230A3).rep(fname);
  }
  }
```

B:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
import "./C.sol";
contract B{
   function rep() public returns(string memory){
      return string(C(0x8fcECc5B8d42EcF099E1cF032B1F505fbDA230A3).name());
   }
   }
```

Comment: So what exactly is `C c=new C()` used for in here???

Comment: It has to be deleted. Sorry for that.

Comment: It was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Note that, in Truffle console, you should try `naming()` just like:

```
A_instance.naming.sendTransaction()
```

or

```
A_instance.naming()
```

This sends a transaction to network that causes your desired code be run. This process mutates ledger and contracts' states. Using `.call()` instead `.sendTransaction()` just makes an interaction between two contracts without mutating their states. It causes their previous state don't mutate and you don't see the new values.

Answer (score 1):

There are some cases maybe you didn't pay attention:

1. You are executing `naming()` from `A` by `.call()` not by `.sendTransaction()`. Obviously, it never mutates the state. I did guess that because of `truffle-contract` that there is in the tags list of your question.
2. Maybe, you made a mistake in inserting the real address of `C` when you call it in both `A` and `B`. I mean here:
   `C(0x8fcECc5B8d42EcF099E1cF032B1F505fbDA230A3).rep(...)`. That can be address of another deployed `C`.
3. The same case @Rob Hitchens answered.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough is known about your tool stack and testing methodology to be sure. The comment about `new C()` suggests a situation that might have been enough to create unexpected results.

Intuitively, it may be about waiting for confirmation. It is almost a rite of passage to get confused about ti.

- A is mutating the state, and that means nothing really happens until the transaction is mined. Mining/confirmation might take some time.
- B is inspecting the state, and the Ethereum node will inspect its local copy of the blockchain without waiting. In particular, without waiting for A to update. It's entirely possible you might think A failed to do its job because you peeked too soon.

The asynchronous nature of this platform takes some getting used to.

Have a look at this explainer to see if any insights or oversights jump out.  https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2

Hope it helps.